# Oracledb add-on binary for node.js 8.17.0( mac 64 intel)

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using nodejs version:- 8.17.0
Oracledb :- 3.0.0

and add oracle instant client 19.1 files to use/local/lib

While running npm run dev:local

I am getting error

NJS-045: cannot load the Oracledb add-on binary for node.js 8.17.0 (darwin X64)

Cannot load project path/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/Oracledb.node

**Note:- I can only use to permit above versions**.

**Mac User**

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from the [node-oracledb 3.0 installation instructions](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/v3.0.1/INSTALL.md#instosx),
make a directory `~/lib/` and link the top level Instant Client shared libary to it.  It's not clear exactly where your library is but with Instant Client extracted in `~/Downloads/instantclient_19_8` I would have tried something like:

```
mkdir ~/lib
ln -s ~/Downloads/instantclient_19_8/libclntsh.dylib ~/lib/
```